# SSIS Package with calculating and comparing checksum

Tags: ssis, checksum

I'm building SSIS Package that gets the data (many csv files) from SFTP which I connected with WinScp via Execute Process Task with bash script. I have to compute SHA256 checksum which I did with this addon - http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Checksum-Transformation.aspx

The main problem is must compare computed checksum with the checksum already provided on SFTP. Is there any tool for doing that? Like a lookup item from toolbox?

Comment: So you computed a checksum column yourself and want to compare it to what comes from the source? You can do this by using a Lookup as you point out, however you need to be sure that is the same checksum algorithm used. Otherwise they properbly wont match.

Comment: The problem is I have to create SSIS package (normally I'd do all of it in Python code but there isn't on the production server and no one knows besides me) which computes SHA256 for each csv, then compares to provided SHA256 by 3rd party. Only idea I got is to try to write another script in PowerShell to generate hash for each csv and then store it into another csv, then load it into staging table and compare two tables - if they match load it into production

Comment: I'm thinking you'd need a Foreach loop to iterate over each csv. You'd calculate the SHA256 for the csv, save it to a variable, and then access that variable in your script task to do the comparison to the checksum from the SFTP server.